# Unable to import pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc

I want to connect SQL server 2012/2014 from my windows machine using Python. For that I installed pyodbc module to my virtual environment using command below

```
pip install pyodbc
```

However, it gave me the message below when I run my script

> ```
> import pyodbc ImportError: No module named pyodbc
> ```

Here is my code:

```
import pyodbc
db= pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}',
                   server='127.0.0.1', 
                   database='master',               
                   trusted_connection='yes')
db.close()
```

The module has already installed and it's listed when I use pip list.
I have been searching around but with no luck on finding the solution on what exactly cause that issue.

Any helps will be appropriated.

Comment: You said virtual environment. Did you run PIP normally or within that environment?

Comment: @gilliduck yes, I ran PIP within the environment without any error meesage and it did show up in the list

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem after using conda to install pyodbc into a conda (virtual) environment and then trying to import into jupyter notebook.

At some point, I tried installing pyodbc *into my base miniconda3* and finally the import in the conda env worked.

*Edit*:  That was not much of a solution, though, and realized wasn't able to import *any* modules installed in the env.

Finally, problem was solved by following **both** option 1 and 2 on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58068818/how-to-use-jupyter-notebooks-in-a-conda-environment).  I.e.

1. activating the env, then *in that env*...
2. conda install jupyter
3. conda install ipykernel
4. ipython kernel install --user --name=my_env

What did not seem to work:
Doing Step 3 above, and then outside the env, c:\users\user\miniconda3\python -m ipykernel install --user --name=my_env

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pip install pyodbc‑4.0.24‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl
```

You can aquire it here : https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyodbc

Look in to the link and download it based on your CPU architecture : 32/64