# Calling a julia function from jupyter notebook (import Julia jupyter notebook)

Tags: import, jupyter-notebook, julia, ijulia-notebook

With Python I can reuse another Jupyter notebook by importing it directly to a new one as a module ([here in Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58068818/how-to-use-jupyter-notebooks-in-a-conda-environment)) or [using `nbpackage`](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html).

Can this be done with Julia Jupyter notebooks? How to import functions from one notebook into another?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to use [`NBInclude.jl`](https://github.com/stevengj/NBInclude.jl) package:

```
using NBInclude
@nbinclude("my_other_jupyter_notebook.ipynb")
```

This construct is analogous to having the code from notebook stored in a `some.jl` file and included as typical:

```
include("some.jl")
```

Please note that there are different scoping considerations at play depending on the version of Julia you use (1.0 or 0.6). Please refer to the [documentation](https://github.com/stevengj/NBInclude.jl).

Installation via:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("NBInclude")
```

or REPL / `]` (package management mode):

```
add NBInclude
```