# Unable to find python package in AWS Jupyter EMR

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, conda, amazon-emr

I am new to AWS EMR Jupyter environment and stuck at installation of python package. I have setup a single node EMR cluster for now, and installed this package looker_sdk in docker container by doing an SSH into the node. I can see its installed and see its available using iPython/python shell and I can import it. But it still fails when I try to import from Jupyter notebook.

```
root@jupyterhub:~# pip freeze | grep looker
WARNING: The directory '/home/jovyan/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
looker-sdk==0.1.3b15
```

But in Jupyter:

```
print(sys.path)
import looker_sdk

['/home/notebook/work', '/opt/conda/lib/python37.zip', '/opt/conda/lib/python3.7', '/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '', '/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awseditorssparkmonitoringwidget-1.0-py3.7.egg', '/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions', '/home/notebook/.ipython']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-f7a797152935> in <module>
      1 print(sys.path)
----> 2 import looker_sdk

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'looker_sdk'
```

Also, the dir listings are giving different results, different users who own the directories.

From Shell in the docker container:

```
root@jupyterhub:~# ls -ltr /opt/conda/
total 56
-rw-rw-r--  1 jovyan users 11245 Mar  3 01:40 LICENSE.txt
drwsrwsr-x  1 jovyan users    21 Mar 17 21:11 x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu
drwsrwsr-x  3 jovyan users    22 Mar 17 21:11 shell
drwsrwsr-x  2 jovyan users    19 Mar 17 21:16 condabin
drwsrwsr-x  2 jovyan users    30 Mar 17 21:16 compiler_compat
drwsrwsr-x  2 jovyan users   203 Mar 17 21:21 sbin
drwsrwsr-x  1 jovyan users   146 Apr  8 21:36 ssl
drwxr-sr-x  3 jovyan users    19 Apr  8 21:37 var
drwxr-sr-x  2 jovyan users   175 Apr  8 21:37 resources
drwxr-sr-x 26 jovyan users  4096 Apr  8 21:37 qml
drwxr-sr-x  2 jovyan users   252 Apr  8 21:37 phrasebooks
drwxr-sr-x 75 jovyan users  4096 Apr  8 21:37 mkspecs
drwxr-sr-x  3 jovyan users    86 Apr  8 21:37 libexec
drwsrwsr-x  1 jovyan users    23 Apr  8 21:37 lib
drwsrwsr-x  1 jovyan users  4096 Apr  8 21:37 include
drwsrwsr-x  1 jovyan users    21 Apr  8 21:37 etc
drwxr-sr-x  3 jovyan users    20 Apr  8 21:37 doc
drwxr-sr-x  3 jovyan users 12288 Apr  8 21:37 translations
drwsrwsr-x  1 jovyan users    21 Apr  8 21:37 share
drwxr-sr-x  3 jovyan users    17 Apr  8 21:37 qsci
drwxr-sr-x 30 jovyan users  4096 Apr  8 21:37 plugins
drwxr-sr-x  3 jovyan users    18 Apr  8 21:37 man
drwsrwsr-x  1 jovyan users    21 Apr  8 21:38 conda-meta
drwsrwsr-x  1 jovyan users   212 Apr  8 21:38 bin
drwsrwsr-x  1 jovyan users    55 Aug  3 12:16 envs
drwxr-sr-x  1 jovyan users  8192 Aug  3 12:56 pkgs
```

From Jupyter:

```
!ls -ltr /opt/conda
total 124
-rw-rw-r--  1 notebook users 11245 Mar  3 01:41 LICENSE.txt
drwsrwsr-x  1 notebook users  4096 Apr 30 01:44 x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu
drwsrwsr-x  3 notebook users  4096 Apr 30 01:44 man
drwsrwsr-x  3 notebook users  4096 Apr 30 01:44 var
drwsrwsr-x  3 notebook users  4096 Apr 30 01:44 doc
drwsrwsr-x  3 notebook users  4096 Apr 30 01:44 shell
drwsrwsr-x  2 notebook users  4096 Apr 30 01:44 envs
drwsrwsr-x  1 notebook users  4096 Apr 30 01:46 etc
drwsrwsr-x  3 notebook users  4096 Apr 30 01:46 qsci
drwsrwsr-x 30 notebook users  4096 Apr 30 01:46 plugins
drwsrwsr-x  2 notebook users  4096 Apr 30 01:47 condabin
drwsrwsr-x  3 notebook users 12288 Apr 30 01:47 translations
drwsrwsr-x  2 notebook users  4096 Apr 30 01:47 resources
drwsrwsr-x 26 notebook users  4096 Apr 30 01:47 qml
drwsrwsr-x  2 notebook users  4096 Apr 30 01:47 phrasebooks
drwsrwsr-x 75 notebook users  4096 Apr 30 01:47 mkspecs
drwsrwsr-x  4 notebook users  4096 Apr 30 01:47 libexec
drwsrwsr-x  2 notebook users  4096 Apr 30 01:47 compiler_compat
drwsrwsr-x  1 root     users  4096 Apr 30 01:50 locks
drwsrwsr-x  1 notebook users  4096 Apr 30 01:53 ssl
drwsrwsr-x  1 notebook users  4096 Apr 30 01:54 share
drwsrwsr-x  1 notebook users  4096 Apr 30 01:54 sbin
drwsrwsr-x  1 notebook users  4096 Apr 30 01:54 lib
drwsrwsr-x  1 notebook users  4096 Apr 30 01:54 include
drwsrwsr-x  1 notebook users  4096 Apr 30 01:57 bin
drwsrwsr-x  1 notebook users  4096 Apr 30 02:02 pkgs
drwsrwsr-x  1 notebook users  4096 Apr 30 02:02 conda-meta
```

I tried to research and read about this, but couldn't find anything that would explain how this is working. Please help here.

**Update:** If we go to the JupyterHub console directly, then we see that user "jovyan" is used. But if we open notebook from the EMR console by attaching the cluster, the user "notebook" is used and none of the changes we did for installing kernel are visible. Will post the answer as soon as I am able to crack this.

Comment: AFAIK, the jupyter of the EMR works on the docker environment.

Comment: You're using Conda?

Comment: yes its conda version 4.8.2 and EMR version 5.30.1