# Issues switching environments inside a jupyter notebook (both open or new)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, conda

I'm trying to use a specific jupyter environment to run a notebook. Ideally I'd like to be able to select the environment from within jupyter, but I would settle at this point for just being able to get the environment to work at all. **How can I get the notebook to recognize another environment either by starting in that environment or by selecting it after starting the notebook?**

The environment name on the drop down menu at the upper right changes, but the environment does not appear to be activated. Nor is the notebook apparently reading the environment that I was in when I started jupyter lab. Here is what I have tried:

I'm running this notebook on a linux server routed through ssh.

I have multiple environments installed using conda, created with .yml files:

```
base                     /FILEPATH/anaconda3
jupyter_env           *  /FILEPATH/anaconda3/envs/jupyter_env
science_env        /FILEPATH/anaconda3/envs/science_env
```

I activated jupyter_env.
I ran this command to add the other environment to the notebook (or so I think):

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name science_env --display-name "science_env"
```

I start a jupyter lab

```
jupyter lab --port 7989 --no-browser &
```

and open either a new notebook or an existing notebook. I can see "science_env" in the upper right under the dropdown box and I can select it.

However if I try to import a package that is in science_env and it fails.
Also if I open a kernel for that notebook and type "conda info" it still says:

```
active environment : jupyter_env
```

Just to check that I have the packages I need installed:
In the terminal window when I use "conda list" to show what is in an environment I see that jupyter_env includes (a relevant section of the list in the i-j range, full lists at the bottom):

```
ipykernel                 5.3.1            py38h23f93f0_0    conda-forge
ipython                   7.16.1           py38h23f93f0_0    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
jedi                      0.17.1           py38h32f6830_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    2.11.2             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
json5                     0.9.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
jsonschema                3.2.0            py38h32f6830_1    conda-forge
jupyter_client            6.1.5                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.6.3            py38h32f6830_1    conda-forge
jupyterlab                2.1.5                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_server         1.2.0                      py_0    conda-forge
```

in science_envs for the same range I have (it's too long to put the whole list - I could add it later if someone things it is relevant):

```
ipykernel                 5.3.4            py37h43977f1_0    conda-forge
ipyleaflet                0.13.3             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
ipython                   7.17.0           py37hc6149b9_0    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.17.2           py37hc8dfbb8_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    2.11.2             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
jmespath                  0.10.0             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
joblib                    0.16.0                     py_0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9d                   h516909a_0    conda-forge
json-c                    0.13.1            hbfbb72e_1002    conda-forge
jsonschema                3.2.0            py37hc8dfbb8_1    conda-forge
jupyter                   1.0.0                      py_2    conda-forge
jupyter_client            6.1.6                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyter_console           6.1.0                      py_1    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.6.3            py37hc8dfbb8_1    conda-forge
jupyterlab                0.35.6                   py37_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_server         0.2.0                      py_0    conda-forge
```

If I activate the science_env environment, then start the jupyter lab it **still does not work**. And if I do "conda list" in the console within a jupyter notebook it does not list the same packages as if I do conda list from the command line. *The list appears to match my base install and not any of my environments.* **How can I get the notebook to recognize another environment either by starting in that environment or by selecting it after starting the notebook?**

I also tried to set this up for another member of my lab and they are having the same problem. Can anyone help me see why this is not working?

Full list of packages in jupyter_env

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       1_gnu    conda-forge
academic                  0.6.2                    pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0    conda-forge
backcall                  0.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
backports                 1.0                        py_2    conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.1                      py_0    conda-forge
bibtexparser              1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
bleach                    3.1.5              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py38h1e0a361_1000    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2020.6.20            hecda079_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2020.6.20        py38h32f6830_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.14.0           py38hd463f26_0    conda-forge
chardet                   3.0.4           py38h32f6830_1006    conda-forge
cryptography              2.9.2            py38h766eaa4_0    conda-forge
decorator                 4.4.2                      py_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.3             py38h32f6830_1001    conda-forge
future                    0.18.2                   pypi_0    pypi
idna                      2.10               pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        1.7.0            py38h32f6830_0    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        1.7.0                         0    conda-forge
ipykernel                 5.3.1            py38h23f93f0_0    conda-forge
ipython                   7.16.1           py38h23f93f0_0    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
jedi                      0.17.1           py38h32f6830_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    2.11.2             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
json5                     0.9.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
jsonschema                3.2.0            py38h32f6830_1    conda-forge
jupyter_client            6.1.5                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.6.3            py38h32f6830_1    conda-forge
jupyterlab                2.1.5                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_server         1.2.0                      py_0    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.34                 hc38a660_9    conda-forge
libffi                    3.2.1             he1b5a44_1007    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 9.2.0                h24d8f2e_2    conda-forge
libgomp                   9.2.0                h24d8f2e_2    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.17               h516909a_0    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              9.2.0                hdf63c60_2    conda-forge
markupsafe                1.1.1            py38h1e0a361_1    conda-forge
mistune                   0.8.4           py38h1e0a361_1001    conda-forge
nb_conda_kernels          2.2.3                    py38_0    conda-forge
nbconvert                 5.6.1            py38h32f6830_1    conda-forge
nbformat                  5.0.7                      py_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.1               hf484d3e_1002    conda-forge
notebook                  6.0.3            py38h32f6830_1    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1g               h516909a_1    conda-forge
packaging                 20.4               pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
pandoc                    2.10.1               h516909a_0    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.4.2                      py_1    conda-forge
parso                     0.7.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.8.0            py38h32f6830_1    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5           py38h32f6830_1001    conda-forge
pip                       20.1.1                     py_1    conda-forge
prometheus_client         0.8.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.5                      py_1    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.6.0                   py_1001    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.20               pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
pygments                  2.6.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 19.1.0                     py_1    conda-forge
pyparsing                 2.4.7              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
pyrsistent                0.16.0           py38h1e0a361_0    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1            py38h32f6830_1    conda-forge
python                    3.8.3           cpython_he5300dc_0    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.8                      1_cp38    conda-forge
pyzmq                     19.0.1           py38ha71036d_0    conda-forge
readline                  8.0                  h46ee950_1    conda-forge
requests                  2.24.0             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
ruamel-yaml               0.16.10                  pypi_0    pypi
ruamel-yaml-clib          0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
send2trash                1.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
setuptools                49.1.0           py38h32f6830_0    conda-forge
six                       1.15.0             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.32.3               hcee41ef_1    conda-forge
terminado                 0.8.3            py38h32f6830_1    conda-forge
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.10               hed695b0_0    conda-forge
toml                      0.10.1                   pypi_0    pypi
tornado                   6.0.4            py38h1e0a361_1    conda-forge
traitlets                 4.3.3            py38h32f6830_1    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.25.9                     py_0    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyh9f0ad1d_1    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
wheel                     0.34.2                     py_1    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.5                h516909a_1    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.2                he1b5a44_2    conda-forge
zipp                      3.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h516909a_1009    conda-forge
```

Comment: Twitter user @frodre pointed me to [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58068818/how-to-use-jupyter-notebooks-in-a-conda-environment) outlining many ways this kernel/jupyter/envionments system can be set up with some trouble shooting tips. Very helpful!

Comment: Duplicate: [Conda environments not showing up in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook). I specifically recommend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43197286/570918).