# Can not run jupyter notebook using anaconda promt

Tags: anaconda, jupyter

I used Anaconda prompt to run Jupyter notebook by command: jupyter notebook but get the error
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
How can I fix this? I try google but look like I'm the only one have this error.

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58068818/how-to-use-jupyter-notebooks-in-a-conda-environment`

Comment: yep, that's a dupe (you don't have jupyter installed)

Comment: @Forest1 Thank you. I solved the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Jupyter notebooks in a conda environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58068818/how-to-use-jupyter-notebooks-in-a-conda-environment)