# import 'tensorflow.keras' could not be resolved problem

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have some problem in my vscode

I can steel import my modules but vscode is saying problems.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iACiu.png)

In my idea it's because some modules are in pypi and some are in conda-forge
but I can't fix it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwknJ.png)

Comment: you should follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58068850/1076264) to enable your environment in notebook

Comment: just a quick note, this will help users assist you better:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: These are just warning messages which will not impact on modules functionality. This bug has already been reported to get this underline error fixed. Please run your code and let us know if any error shows up.