# Conda env package not being used in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda, environment

I can't get Jupyter to use the environment I activated

I have created an environment in conda. After activating the env using conda prompt, and using `conda list`, I see my pandas version installed is 1.5.3

While in myenv, I run `jupyter notebook`.
I have installed nb_conda, and have selected the kernel that shows "Python [conda env:myenv]" on Jupyter.

However, in the notebook I run the two lines below:
`import pandas`
`pandas.__version__`

and get '2.1.3' version which is on my base env.

How do I get Jupyter to use myenv I activated?

Comment: Any chance you are falling prey to the pitfall of "jupyter notebook is not (fully) installed in the conda environment, even if which jupyter might make you believe it was", discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58068850/8508004)? I imagine you installed ipykernel in the environment as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43197286/8508004) since it shows up as an option to choose as a kernel?

Comment: I believe so, I have ran:
`conda install -n myenv ipykernel`
`conda activate myenv`
`pip install ipykernel`
`python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv --display-name "Python (myenv)"`
`conda install nb_conda_kernels`

Comment: You've shut down everything since this and restarted? Anything about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77528944/8508004) jump out as something to try? I'll note that as "to install nb_conda_kernels in your jupyter environment " in that last link highlights the order really matters. As well as where run. Hard to tell from comments alone where and what you've run. (That should be in the post if you can edit it still?)

Comment: Update: finally figured out at least part of it, but am now able to get my desired outcome. Even though `conda list` showed my pandas version was 1.5.3 in myenv, in Anaconda Navigator the pandas version is 2.1.3. So I suspect the jupyter notebook was loading the packages in myenv correctly. 

**The issue is that `conda list` in myenv somehow gives me the wrong version.** I did a pip force reinstall on pandas in myenv, and am now able to load the version I want to Jupyter notebook.